# how to enlarge the video size for compressed video file formats

Tags: video, media-player, video-conversion

I have movie files of format *.mpg. When I try to play these files with my DVD player, in TV the picture size shows up very small compared to TV size, the picture is  aligned in the center with size of some 6 X 7 inches.. This is certain I guess, because TV knows to display pixel ration that is defined it cannot maximize the size by itself.. while if I play it in desktop .. in some media players like vlc, kodec player.. I can go with full screen .. coz these software some how know to maximize with undefined pixels too ..

Now what I need is to convert this movie file such a way that .. it appears full screen in my TV .. (it may not be a clear picture though)

I tried .. xilisoft video converter.. I set the maximum video size the maximum that is possible. but the video size on my television appears almost same ..

Its not the problem with either the converter or television, but its with the downloaded file .. which is compressed version, has low pixel definition..
How to increase the pixel ratio?
any software exist as such??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used xilisoft video converter, I converted *avi format to HDTV TS MPEG *mpg format .. its getting displayed full-screen now .. 50% problem solved but for conversion it takes a lot of time .. on average 7+ hours :( .. mine is 32 inch tv, don't know how much pixel its up with..

Comment: Better hardware is pretty much the only way to make it faster. It's possible that other software using a different algorithm could shave off some time, but it wouldn't be significant.

Answer (score 0):

No way to solve the problem. You can't make the file have more information than it has.
 You can try to work around the issue. Couldn't you try to make say vlc work in full-screen on TV? I don't know how your TV is set up, but it should be enough to just drag the VLC window over to the TV and play the movie, right click on the video and select video->full screen.

It should scale the video across the TV's screen. There will be degradation of quality, but it should be full screen.

Comment: Don't know what you tried to say from second line ..
I just gave clarification why it doesn't show problem while playing on PC but on playing on Television .. vlc on tv ?? sorry couldn't get .. :(

Comment: the problem happens when OP is playing video files with a **DVD player**.

Comment: I somehow missed that... I understood that the TV is connected to computer. :(

Answer (score 0):

What does playback look like when you play a standard retail DVD?  i.e., Do they playback full-screen?  Also, what size is the television on which you're trying to play it back?

Despite TVs getting larger, the DVD standard still only allows for 720x480 pixels (and that's non-square pixels.  With square pixels it ultimately drops to 640x480.).  If your TV is larger than that (e.g., an HDTV @ 720p or larger), either the DVD player or the television is going to have to scale those pixels up to fit the display.  i.e., It's going to have to be a function of your display or DVD player, because you can't put an image larger than 720x480 on a standard DVD for playback.  However, if standard retail DVDs fill up your entire screen, then you may be encoding an image smaller than 720x480.

Comment: I used xilisoft video converter, I converted *avi format to HDTV TS MPEG *mpg format .. its getting displayed full-screen now .. 50% problem solved but for conversion it takes a lot of time .. on average 7+ hours :( ..
mine is 32 inch tv, don't know how much pixel its up with..